# Fresh Ubuntu install crashed while connect to wireless. Rtl8821ce

Tags: wireless, crash, realtek

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu (dual boot windows) on my lenovo e570 with a wireless driver rtl8821ce realtek.

Everything works fine expect wifi.
Before I was working with Kali linux but on that driver I could not make a connection with wifi now on Ubuntu I have wifi but as soon as I connect to wireless it runs for 2 minutes and then Ubuntu freezes and have to do a hard reset.

I tried to reinstall a new driver from tomaspinho succesfully but the problem still continues.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I have been having the same issue on ubuntu 21.10. I tried reinstalling with no luck

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on Ubuntu 21.10. Earlier versions run fine. And this is happening only for rtl8821ce. I tried on system with rtl8723de. There it works fine. Must be due to some bug in the rtw_pci driver.